# How is it possible to display the date from database through javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

Good day! Is is possible to output the date from database through javascipt?I am working in a chart and I want to output the date from my database through my json.php but can I display these dates?

Comment: I think you want to add a little more detail.

Comment: As @deg mentioned, more detail. It's a good idea to tell us more specifics. give a short block of code that you have attempted. To answer your question. Yes. it is possible.